# Why do JasperReport with crosstab output to excel fails with large number of columns?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, crosstab

We have number of row as 500 and columns as 68. We want to output this data into excel. We are using crosstab in jrxml for same.Out of 68 columns we have defined 16 as row group and 52 as column ( this is dynamic) in my example the dynamic payload i have about 52.

With this payload and output the program that generates output has memory capacity of 2Gb. Using jasper reports v.6.6 the process gives out of memory.

In [eclipse mat](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G96Fu0EFiAa-zCYLU4wZplflOvZSU_lL) we are seeing leak suspect in BuckingService.

I attach the sample [jrxml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KFHBOPqlU-G-wA-WNkJ9IJShlxSqMRtR) with sample [json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eeaP7pExnwhNvuq9FoHtmc-y6vyGrLZ4) that has 500 row and 68 columns.

Is there a limit on number of dynamic columns in crosstab?

With above configuration reducing number of dynamic columns to 10 i.e. total of 26 columns(16 rowgroup, 10 columngroup) crosstab generate excel report successfully with above same parameter and memory limits.

The attached Sample.jrxml and sampleAllWeek.json(56 column) fails with out of memory. 
when export jrxml to excel.

Is it possible to achieve export of 56 columns with unlimited row in 2Gb memory, where jasper report has crosstab?

Comment: i tried virtualization too both JRSwapFileVirtualizer and JRGzipVirtualizer however that too fails with out of memory. is it possible to generate multiple JasperPrint given json data page wise for same template and then output it in single xlsx in pdf. Will it help out of memory issue with export large number of columns data with huge number of rows.

Comment: can someone pls guide